# C# How to set button text of different buttons to the same textbox

Tags: c#, asp.net, button, textbox

I have a couple of buttons and a textbox. I want to make it so that when I press button1 the text from the textbox goes to button and when I press button2 the text goes to button2 and so on. I now have this:

```
protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        Button1.Text = TextBox1.Text;
    }

    protected void Button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Button2.Text = TextBox1.Text;
    }

    protected void Button3_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Button3.Text = TextBox1.Text;
    }
```

**Edit:** Is there a shorter way to do this?

Comment: `((Button)sender).Text = TextBox1.Text;`

Comment: do you need the pressing of the button?

Comment: Yes, when I click on a button I want the text from the textbox to go on the button.

Comment: then the comment by @EdPlunkett is your solution

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you point the `Click` event for each button to the same method you can have this in one method like so;

```
protected void Button_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    ((Button)sender).Text = TextBox1.Text;
}
```

You can change the method that is used for a button event in the designer by clicking on the button, going to the Properties window and clicking on the little lightening symbol for events and selecting the `Button_Click` method for the `Click` event.